# FreeMarker XML Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, freemarker

How can we obtain the XPath of a node in FreeMarker. I want to know the synatax .
Like if I am processing a node and want to get its address in XML.

Something like : node?node_xpath .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such thing exists out of the box. You could write a custom method (`TemplateMethodModelEx` implementation) for it. What kind of path do you need anyway? Something like `/node()[0]/node()[3]/node()[2]`? I believe the W3C DOM API has no method to query the index of a node, so you have to scan through the children of the parent of the node to find out its index. (That's a DOM limitation, not a FreeMarker limitation.) Or if you know more about the schema, you may want something like `/foo/bar[@id=123]/baaz`, but that won't be a general-purpose function, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class GetXPathFromNode implements TemplateMethodModelEx {

public Object exec(List args) throws TemplateModelException {

    if(args.size() != 1){
         throw new TemplateModelException("Please specify one xml node.");
    }

    NodeModel node = (NodeModel) args.get(0);

    return getXPath(node.getNode());

}

private String getXPath(Node node) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/");
    String attribute = "";
    if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE){
        attribute = "/@" + node.getNodeName();
        Attr attr = (Attr) node;
        node = attr.getOwnerElement();
    }

    sb.append(node.getNodeName())
    .append("[").append(getNodeIndex(node)).append("]").append(attribute);

    return renderNodeXpath(node, sb).toString();
}

private StringBuilder renderNodeXpath(Node node, StringBuilder path){

    Node parentNode = node.getParentNode();
    if(parentNode != null && parentNode.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE){
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("/");
        sb2.append("[").append(getNodeIndex(parentNode)).append("]");
        path.insert(0,sb2);
        return renderNodeXpath(parentNode, path);

    }
    return path;

}

private int getNodeIndex(Node childNode) {

    Node parentNode = childNode.getParentNode();
    if(parentNode == null){
        return 1;
    }


    int index = 1;
    for(int i = 0; parentNode.getChildNodes().getLength() >= i; i++){
        Node node = parentNode.getChildNodes().item(i);

        if(node.isSameNode(childNode)){
            return index; // this is used to ignore empty text nodes.
        }
        if(node.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE){
            index++;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

}
```